# Basic operations combining two SharedArrays

Tags: arrays, function, parallel-processing, julia

I've spent the last month or so learning julia and I'm very impressed. In particular I'm analysing large amount of climate model output, I put all this into `SharedArrays` and adjust and plot it all in parallel. So far it's very quick and efficient and I've got quite a library of code. My current problem is in creating a function that can do basic operations on  two shared arrays. I've successfully written a function that takes two arrays and how you want to process them. The code is based around the example in the parallel section of the julia doc and uses the `myrange` function as shown there

```
function myrange(q::SharedArray)
    idx = indexpids(q)
    #@show (idx)
    if idx == 0
        # This worker is not assigned a piece
        return 1:0, 1:0
        print("NO WORKERS ASSIGNED")
    end
    nchunks = length(procs(q))
    splits = [round(Int, s) for s in linspace(0,length(q),nchunks+1)]
    splits[idx]+1:splits[idx+1]
end

function combine_arrays_chunk!(array_1,array_2,output_array,func, length_range);
    #@show (length_range)
    for i in length_range
        output_array[i] = func(array_1[i], array_2[i]);
        #hardwired example for func = +
        #output_array[i] = +(array_1[i], array_2[i]);
    end
    output_array
end

combine_arrays_shared_chunk!(array_1,array_2,output_array,func) = combine_arrays_chunk!(array_1,array_2,output_array,func, myrange(array_1));

function combine_arrays_shared(array_1::SharedArray,array_2::SharedArray,func)
    if size(array_1)!=size(array_2)
        return print("inputs not of the same size")
    end
    output_array=SharedArray(Float64,size(array_1));
    @sync begin
        for p in procs(array_1)
            @async remotecall_wait(p, combine_arrays_shared_chunk!, array_1,array_2,output_array,func)
        end
    end
    output_array
end
```

The works so one can do

```
strain_div  = combine_arrays_shared(eps_1,eps_2,+);
strain_tot  = combine_arrays_shared(eps_1,eps_2,hypot);
```

with the correct results an the output as a shared array as required. But ... it's quite slow. It's actually quicker to combine the `sharedarray` as a normal array on one processor, calculate and then convert back to a `sharedarray` (for my test cases anyway, with each array approx 200MB, when I move up to GBs I guess not). I can hardwire the `combine_arrays_shared` function to only do addition (or some other function), and then you get the speed increase, but with function type being passed within `combine_arrays_shared` the whole thing is slow (10 times slower than the hard wired addition).

I've looked at the `FastAnonymous.jl` package but I can't see how it would work in this case. I tried, and failed. Any ideas?

I might just resort to writing a different `combine_arrays_...` function for each basic function I use, or having the `func` argument as a option and call different functions from within `combine_arrays_shared`, but I want it to be more elegant! Also this is good way to learn more about Julia.

Harry

Answer (score 1):

This question actually has nothing to do with SharedArrays, and is just "how do I pass functions-as-arguments and get better performance?"

The way FastAnonymous works---and similar to the way closures will work in julia soon---is to create a type with a `call` method. If you're having trouble with FastAnonymous for some reason, you can always do it manually:

```
julia> immutable Foo end

julia> Base.call(f::Foo, x, y) = x*y
call (generic function with 1036 methods)

julia> function applyf(f, X)
           s = zero(eltype(X))
           for x in X
               s += f(x, x)
           end
           s
       end
applyf (generic function with 1 method)

julia> X = rand(10^6);

julia> f = Foo()
Foo()

# Run the function once with each type of argument to JIT-compile
julia> applyf(f, X)
333375.63216645207

julia> applyf(*, X)
333375.63216645207

# Compile anything used by @time
julia> @time 1
  0.000004 seconds (148 allocations: 10.151 KB)
1

# Now let's benchmark
julia> @time applyf(f, X)
  0.002860 seconds (5 allocations: 176 bytes)
333433.439233112

julia> @time applyf(*, X)
  0.142411 seconds (4.00 M allocations: 61.035 MB, 19.24% gc time)
333433.439233112
```

Note the big increase in speed and greatly-reduced memory consumption.

Comment: So an example of getting the question right! This makes more sense now, so I can assign the type f to the function I need and then the function is passed efficiently. Is there a way I can assign this type within the function? So for my example above, the top  `combine_arrays_shared` would do the assigning, then the function is passed efficiently to the `combine_arrays_chunk!` function? I'll give it a go.